# How to disable and grey out a flutter button until the form is completely filled and then enable it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've been designing a payment reminder app in which I have added multiple text fields. So I want to grey out the *next* button unless all the `TextField()` widgets have been correctly filled.

Comment: Can you add sample code snippet that will reproduce the issue,

Comment: So, what of the above *can* you do so far and where *exactly* are you stuck? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  final TextEditingController _controller1 = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controller2 = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controller3 = TextEditingController();
  bool _isFullyEntered = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller1.addListener(() {
      _isFullyEntered = _checkFullyEntered();
      setState((){});
    });
    _controller2.addListener(() {
      _isFullyEntered = _checkFullyEntered();
      setState((){});
    });
    _controller3.addListener(() {
      _isFullyEntered = _checkFullyEntered();
      setState((){});
    });
  }

  bool _checkFullyEntered(String text){
    if(_controller1.text == '') return false;
    if(_controller2.text == '') return false;
    if(_controller3.text == '') return false;
    
    return true;
  }

  Button(
    color: _isFullyEntered ? Colors.grey : Colors.orange,
    onPressed: _isFullyEntered ? () {/*your function*/} : () {};
```